How do I learn about Rockets and planes?
I want to learn how to make aeroplanes and rocket, how they work, etc. I want to be able to make working models. How do I go about it, what books can i read, what videos can I watch for easy, clear and deep understanding of the topic?

Do research - check out manufacturers like Boeing, Airbus. Check out books about flight.

join a model airplane club

Easy, clear, and deep understanding are probably mutually exclusive.  People spend their entire careers increasing their understanding on a topic as deep and broad as this.
